# Porque esta funcion no hace nada y no obtengo un error al respecto?

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una funcion para calcular un campo que es el producto de dos input fields, pero no esta funcionando. Lo raro es que cuando inspecciono la consola, no me devuelve ningun tipo de error.

Esta es mi funcion

```
function CalcularNacionalizacion(){
    var fob = document.getElementById('fob');
    var factorNac = document.getElementById('nacFactor');
    var Nacionalizacion = fob * nacFactor;
    document.getElementById('costNacionalizacion').value = Nacionalizacion;
}
```

Y estos son los tres campos que se ven involucrados en mi funcion:

```
               <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="fob">Costo Fob</label>
                    <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="fob" name="fob" class="form-control" onchange="CalcularNacionalizacion();" onkeyup="CalcularNacionalizacion();" required>
                </div>

                

                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="nacFactor">Factor de Nacionalizacion</label>
                    <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="nacFactor" name="nacFactor" class="form-control" onchange="CalcularNacionalizacion();" onkeyup="CalcularNacionalizacion();" required>
                </div>

              <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="costNacionalizacion">Costo Nacionalizacion</label>
                    <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="costNacionalizacion" name="costNacionalizacion" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
```

Comment: Con los getelementbyid estas tomando el objeto. Debes poner .value seguido para tomar el valor almacenado en el objeto

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que veo es que estas intentando multiplicar una variable que no existe.

```
var fob = document.getElementById('fob');
    var factorNac = document.getElementById('nacFactor');
    var Nacionalizacion = fob * nacFactor;
```

En la tercera linea de la multiplicación estas haciendo la operación con la identidad del objeto y no con la variable que has creado.

Debería ser así

```
var Nacionalizacion = fob * factorNac;
```

Por otra parte, si quieres sacar el valor le tendrías que añadir el value como te comento el compañero Hernán Garcia.

Answer (score 1):

Yo corrí tu código y sí me tiró error: The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range. Eso significa que estabas intentando multiplicar texto, y no número (not a number).
Agregué a tu código el .value, como indicaron anteriormente, para decirle que quiero q tome el valor y no el objeto, y le agregué parseInt, para que convierta ese valor a un número y no a un string, quedando así:

```js
function CalcularNacionalizacion(){
    var fob = document.getElementById('fob');
    var factorNac = document.getElementById('nacFactor');
    var Nacionalizacion = parseInt(fob.value) * parseInt(nacFactor.value);
    
    document.getElementById('costNacionalizacion').value = Nacionalizacion;
}
```

Lo que me desconcierta es que me olvidé de corregir la variable inexistente, pero igualmente corre bien! Eso ya es para una pregunta aparte XD

Comment: Diria que la variable inexistente no te da error porque coges el valor directamente de la identidad.